# How to combine a blink function with a toggle function?

Tags: python, oop, tkinter

I have a function that refreshes a string. It has 2 buttons, on and off. If you push on it will print 'Test' multiple times per second.

```
def blink():
    def run():
        while (switch):
            print('Test')

    thread = threading.Thread(target=run)
    thread.start()

def on():
    global switch
    switch = True
    blink()


def off():
    global switch
    switch = False
```

I also have a toggle function that's is one button that toggles 'True' and 'False'. It displays 'Test' when True.

```
def toggle():
    if button1.config('text')[-1] == 'False':
        button1.config(text='True')
        Label(root, text='Test').place(x=30, y=0, relheight=1, relwidth=0.7)

    else:
        button1.config(text='False')
        Label(root, text='').place(x=30, y=0, relheight=1, relwidth=0.7)
```

How do I combine these 2? What I want is that instead of having an on/off button, I have one toggle-able button.

I tried making a class:

```
class Toggle:

    def blink():
        def run():
            while (switch):
                print('Test')
                Label(root, text='Test').place(x=30, y=0, relheight=1, relwidth=0.7)
            else:
                Label(root, text='').place(x=30, y=0, relheight=1, relwidth=0.7)

        thread = threading.Thread(target=run)
        thread.start()

    def toggle():
        if button1.config('text')[-1] == 'False':
            button1.config(text='True')
            global switch
            switch = True
            blink()

        else:
            button1.config(text='False')
            global switch
            switch = False
```

But I get an error:

```
  File "C:\Users\Daniel\PycharmProjects\stockalarm test\main.py", line 29
global switch
^
SyntaxError: name 'switch' is assigned to before global declaration
```

I tried looking into it but I cant figure out what to do.

Comment: Where does this `switch` variable come from, it's in the `run` function inside `blink` method but it doesn't seem to be declared there

Comment: Anyways, you're using a class, use `self.switch` and try to avoid the `global` keyword whenever you can

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, if you use a class then `switch` should be an attribute of the class instead of being a global variable.

Additionally, what you did is more CLI oriented and what I suggest below is to use a more tkinter oriented approach.

1. You want a "toggle-able" button, which is, I think, like a `tk.Checkbutton` with the `indicatoron` option set to False.
2. Instead of using the `switch` global variable, you can use a `tk.BooleanVar` connected to the state of the `button1` checkbutton.
3. This depends on what you actually want to do in the `run()` function but in your example using `threading.Thread` is an overkill. You can use tkinter `.after(<delay in ms>, <callback>)` method instead.

I have made the `Toggle` class inherit from `tk.Frame` to put both the label and toggle button inside. Here is the code:

```
import tkinter as tk

class Toggle(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, master=None, **kw):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master, **kw)

        self.label = tk.Label(self)  
        self.switch = tk.BooleanVar(self) 
        self.button1 = tk.Checkbutton(self, text='False', command=self.toggle,
                                         variable=self.switch, indicatoron=False)

        self.label.pack()
        self.button1.pack()

    def blink(self):
        if self.switch.get():  # switch is on
            print('Test')
            self.after(10, self.blink)  # re-execute self.blink() in 10 ms

    def toggle(self):
        if self.switch.get():  # switch on
            self.button1.configure(text='True')  # set button text to True
            self.label.configure(text='Test')       # set label text to Test
            self.blink()                            # start blink function
        else:  # switch off
            self.button1.configure(text='False')
            self.label.configure(text='')


root = tk.Tk()
Toggle(root).pack()
root.mainloop()
```